# Problem with content appended to a collapsable element

Tags: jquery-mobile, collapsable

I have a collapsable section on a page to which I append more elements with an ajax-call, once the collapsable header is pressed. That works fine, the progress bar appears

> $("div#showTicketForm").live("expand", function() {
>
> ```
>   if (!isFormLoaded) {
>       $.mobile.pageLoading();             
>       $.get(
>           "<c:url value='/Controller' />",
>           "page=form&id=${id}&sub=${sub}",
>           function(data) {
>               $("div#showTicketForm").append(data).page();
>               isFormLoaded = true;
>               $.mobile.pageLoading(true);
>       });         
>   }
> ```
>
> });

The problem is that, the added content does not collapse when clickign the header.

How can that be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

[edit]

Sorry, I didn't read carefully. You are using `.page` :P

Your problem is that an element can't be `.page`d more than once. You have to either recreate the div you refer to as `div#showTicketForm` or create a new div in it.